# Pentaho Authentication Method

Tags: authentication, pentaho

I want to integrate Pentaho with C#/VB.NET platform.
For the Pentaho Authentication, there is defualt login page for user console.

http://db.tt/bXcaTgpE

If I do not want use above login page to login, I want to login in code behind, I knew there are following method to do
1) CAS SSO
2) pass parameter like querystring to the url eg http://x.x.x.x/pentaho/Login?use...sword=password

Except above 2 method, do you know other solution for C#/VB.NET?

Method 1) CAS SSO is most common solution but I have no much time to investgate. 
Method 2) is most simple solution but it is not secure that can find the password easily from web browser)

Thanks you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Integrated Windows Authentication. there's a way to use it with Pentaho. It's described here:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0P0/150/010/060/010

Comment: Hi, the link says "page not found"!!

Comment: Edited answer and updated URL to the new documentation site